# Setup read-only vendor SVN repository as mirror/external within my own repository

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu, tortoisesvn

Currently I am working on opencart site and I would like to integrate opencarts source into my own SVN (https://github.com/opencart/opencart).

The goal is to be able to make my own customizations to core OpenCart files and then, when a new version of open cart is released, integrate there changes into my local version.

I was thinking of source structure as follows:

- `/trunk/opencart` - my custom version of open cart
- `/vendor/opencart` - the current opencart trunk.

The intended workflow would be to pull the latest open cart from their servers, then perform a local merge into my trunk.  Currently, I have been struggling to set this up correctly as I am very new to SVN and TortoiseSVN.

My current setup, is Windows7 running TortoiseSVN 1.8.0, Build 24401 - 64 Bit. On my local server I have Ubuntu 13.04 64bit with svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830).

I managed to setup repository that I can check into and out of, and created an external reference in vendor folder using externals.  But I’m struggling to generate the main trunk from this external data. When I try to branch from `vendor/opencart` to `trunk/opencart`, it attempts to generated that branch on `https://github.com/opencart/opencart` rather than my local server. (This rightly fails as the repository is read only).

If I try to perform a merge in SVN on the empty `trunk/opencart` folder with `vendor/opencart` I also get problems as there is lack of ancestry in the trunk folder.  I've read multiple sources - some say to use my approach, some say I should be using svnsync.

What is the best/simplest approach?   Ideally, I would like SVN to pull the latest source, rather than dumping the source into a separate folder.

Comment: it hurts my heart to see someone chain a git repo into a svn repo.

Comment: The online book [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html) contains a whole section on managing [Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html). I strongly recommend reading it, because it explains it quite well. Note that `svn:externals` are not used.

Comment: @mnagel:  I've chosen SVN over git, as it allows me to require users to get a lock on binary files.  Which from my understanding is against the philosophy of how git works?

Comment: @nosid: I’ve read about vendor branches chapter, and as you rightly say they don’t refer to externals being used.   But I get the impression from reading articles here it can be, I am just not entirely clear what best workflow should be.

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant you are right about that and git is not perfect for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-read about svn:externals in Subversion
2. Get Subversion URL for this Git repository (SVN can't directly communicate with Git) - it's "Subversion checkout URL" in sidebar, open it in Repo-browser and select needed subtree for you - it can be some branch or trunk, remember full URL to needed subtree (it can be, f.e., https://github.com/opencart/opencart/trunk/upload)
3. Define, where in your repository you want to mount external repo (let it be /vendor/opencart URL)
4. Checkout parent of mount-point (or parent of parent for our case, if parent still doesn't exist) into new unrelated to work, Working Copy
5. Create in WC root new folder (usual, ordinary, standard) vendor
6. For folder `vendor` add new svn-propery svn:externals in TSVN's wizard
7. Commit changes
8. Check results

**PS:** you can see (checkout, inspect) at this URL https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-troubleshoot-b/trunk as sample of simplest use-case for externals (subdirectory `lib` in trunk is svn:external to another repository subtree)

**PPS:** At staring point you trunk can be empty, you merge `/vendor/opencart` in order to get initial vanilla state of code in trunk for your own changes on top of it

[image: Externals sample]

Comment: I’ve read both Vendor Branches and about svn:externals, but I still seem to be unstuck. I’ve mounted my external repo to myproject/vendor/opencart_trunk/.

The problem I’m getting is merging the starting point to my trunk
Myproject/trunk/
In TortiousSVN, it offers three options; 
 Merge a range of revisions,
 Reintegrate a branch / automatic merge,
 Merge two different trees.
If I pick the first option, it gives me tree conflicts when merging.
If I pick the second option, it crashes (with no error) when attempting to merge.
What it the correct way to perform the merge at this point?

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant - Well, I got this very strange result also (10 tree conflicts, 2 copy). It's something 1.8-specific behavior, I suppose. Will think

Comment: any further infor you get will be much apperciated.  Do you think my SVN and TortiouSVN versions are conflicting?

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant - 1.8 client will play nicely with 1.7 server. Long time ago (1.6 or 1.7 era) I had create trunk in your case by exporting HEAD of vendor-code and adding it into WC of trunk by hand