# merge changes with GIT and SVN

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn

Here is my problem. I am working with an external consultant, who created some code that he keeps in a GIT repo on github. Internally I have a development server that has SVN, and I can make a copy of his code in my internal SVN repo. I don't want to give my consultant direct access to my internal server, but I want to be able to have any changes he makes (and saves on github) to merge with what is in my SVN repo. This does not have to be automatic whenever he updates github - I just want to have a fairly simple process that I can run to merge his changes into my internal SVN repo. Note that I will also be making changes myself to the code in the SVN repo, so I can't just mirror his github git repo to SVN every time he makes changes. So how can I make sure the SVN repo can keep track of changes that both of us make?

Comment: Not a solution to a particular problem - but an advise - upgrade to git: distributed VCS is superior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone your repo with `git-svn` and add his repo as a remote. Now you can merge his changes into your svn whenever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657147/setup-read-only-vendor-svn-repository-as-mirror-external-within-my-own-repositor) (with comments and warnings).

In short - you can use SVN-client for accessing Git-repo, *hosted on Github*, but "dumb" merging of externals and local may be troublesome (test *your case*)